# Implementing a 60 second countdown timer in a print statement in python

Tags: python

How do I implement a 60 second count down timer in a print statement, which only updates the seconds value without affecting the string in the print statement? This is for a Linux terminal.

Comment: Is this question specifically about the PyCharm IDE? If not, please adjust your tags.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your problem? Also, I hope this is not a homework question.

Comment: Its not a homework Question. I need to print 'do you need more time' with a 60 second count down on the same line and only updating the countdown not the entire print statement.

Comment: Based on your comments on replies it sounds like you've already tried a few things; generally it's a good idea to share those (including a minimal snippet of code that shows the problem) in the question text so that we can better understand the specific issues you're facing - e.g. what you say about text that users type being deleted.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds vaguely homework-y, so I'm going to try to give you tools to solve it rather than a ready-made solution.

First of all, to wait one second:

```
from time import sleep

print('Starting...')
sleep(1)
print('It's now been one second')
```

Second of all, to update a string on the screen:

```
print('This is the first string', end='\r')
print('This is the second string, which overwrites the first')
```

The `end='\r'` tells Python that, instead of moving down a line on the terminal at the end, it should go back to the beginning of the same line (and thus the next print statement will overwrite the previous). `\r` stands for "carriage return", an old typewriter term. (The default for `end` is `\n`, for "new line".)

Third, to count down from 60:

```
for secs in range(60, 0, -1):
    print('Time remaining:', secs)
```

This will print `60`, then `59`, then `58`, and so on, all the way down to `1`. Then it'll stop. In the `range` call the first argument is where to start, the second argument is where to stop, and the third argument is the step size.

Between these three you should have all the tools you need to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3:

```
print(60,"\r",end="")
```

"\r" means carriage return, it sets the typing cursor back to the begining of current line. end="" overrides default print function behavior, which makes every print end with a new line character. Your countdown can be achieved like that:

```
from time import sleep
for i in range(0,60):
    print(60-i,end=" /r")
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: You can also lock the sleep to the system time for greater accuracy by recording the start time using `start = time()` and calling `sleep(1.0 - ((time() - start) % 1.0))` for the sleep.

Comment: The reason I mention this is, on my system at least, using a standard 1 second sleep after a print statement actually lasted 60.70536756515503 seconds, while the system time method self corrects every ~10ms of drift, so 60 seconds took 60.00050926208496 seconds. It's easy to see how that can compound over say an hour wait.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
import sys
import time


msg = "hello world"

for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\r{} {}seconds ".format(msg, i))
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Also take a look at the `tqdm` library in python :).

```
https://tqdm.github.io/

$ seq 9999999 | tqdm --bytes | wc -l
75.2MB [00:00, 217MB/s]
9999999
$ 7z a -bd -r backup.7z docs/ | grep Compressing | \
    tqdm --total $(find docs/ -type f | wc -l) --unit files >> backup.log
100%|███████████████████████████████▉| 8014/8014 [01:37<00:00, 82.29files/s]
```

Comment: This is similar to what i have, The main problem I am facing, is when i type on the terminal beside the print statement it gets deleted every second. I was wondering can i split the line in two eg. (print ' you have ' + secs + ' to answer')  and only have the seconds updating.